# Laravel couldn't detect my database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

after creating database on `phpmyadmin` and install `laravel`, `laravel` couldn't detect my database and i get this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)
```

my migrate class:

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        ...
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

this commands couldn't resolve my problem

```
php artisan migrate
composer dump-autoload
```

my username and password to connect to database is correct and my Permission model is:

```
class Permission extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name' , 'label'];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

i'm not sure why `Eloquent` in this code as `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`
 is unknown

Answer (score 0):

try this **php artisan migrate:refresh** This command will delete and recreate the database.

Ok if that does not work. Navigate to App/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.
Add this to import the permission class at the top **use App\Permission;**
Then paste this code beneath the other functions.

```html
 protected function getPermissions()
    {
        try {
            return Permission::with('roles')->get();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Then run php artisan migrate:refresh on the command line again.

Comment: Did you define your database name and host in your env file?  Check to see if the database name, host and password corresponds to what you have in your phpmyadmin.

Comment: Can u log into your phpmyadmin and create a new user and password and change them in your .env file accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159700/discussion-between-olasunkanmi-and-mahdi-pishguy).

Answer (score 0):

And if you create 1 table per migration?

Create a separate permissions table migration